# How to deselect only some rows in a grid?

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid with all its rows selected, there is a column named CODE and what I need its only deselect those rows after clicking a button which CODE is 1 and let selected the other ones.

I have tried with deselectAll(); but this deselect all the rows in the grid.

Comment: I found out how to do it by using deselect(row); thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deselect` method on `selectionModel` to remove the selection of an item. You can pass either array of records to be deselected or an index of record. Below is the sample code.

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone']
});

var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    data: [{
            name: 'Lisa'
        }, {
            name: 'Bart'
        }, {
            name: 'Homer'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: userStore,
    storeId: 'mystore',
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Application Users',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            this.getSelectionModel().select(1, true); 
        }
    },
    tbar: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: "Deselect",
            handler: function() {
                this.up('grid').getSelectionModel().deselect(1); //deseleting record on 1st index
            }
        }    
    ],
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        width: 300,
        sortable: false,
        hideable: false,
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }]
});
```